# How to set height of element using variable in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to set the height of a WPF element using C# to a programatically calculated value.

I've already tried the obvious of setting the height to a variable, a constant variable and just straight-up writing the calculation during the assignment.

```
Image image1 = new Image()
{
    Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill,
    Height = (450 / 650) * 260
};
```

I'm expecting that the image appears with the size 260x180, but the image doesn't appear at all. Setting the Height to be 180 (the outcome of the calculation) makes it look as expected, though.

How do I fix it and why does it happen?

Comment: Please provide more code - a xaml code and the method where you try to change the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your calculations not to use integers

```
Image image1 = new Image()
{
    Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill,
    Height = ((double)450 / (double)650) * (double)260
};
```

Didn't test it, but something like this should do the trick.
The problem is that 450 / 650 is 0 when using int.
Maybe `260 * 450 / 650` works too.